# Rails: Why isn't my custom stylesheet overriding the font family?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass, sprockets

I have [Skeleton](http://getskeleton.com/) boilerplate css in my app. It lives in `app/assets/stylesheets`.

```
app/assets/stylesheets
├── application.css
├── custom.scss
├── normalize.css
└── skeleton.css
```

Skeleton uses a sans-serif font family (with Raleway on the top). I want to override this.

So my custom SCSS file looks like this:

```
@import "skeleton";

body {
  font-family: serif;
}

main {
  @extend .container;
}
```

But the font remains sans-serif.

Now, I believe my custom SCSS file is being loaded before Skeleton because without the `@import "skeleton"`, `@extend .container` (`.containter` is defined in Skeleton) does not work.

I have tried requiring `custom.scss` last in `application.css` like this:

```
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 *= require custom
```

and like this with Skeleton and its associate normalize sheet:

```
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 *= require normalize
 *= require skeleton
 *= require custom
```

But still, I find I need to import Skeleton in my custom file and I cannot override the font-family without using `!important`.

What is going on? Am I right in believing my custom stylesheet is being loaded before Skeleton? How do I ensure my stylesheet loads last?

Answer (score 0):

A simple hack can be, rename your style sheet something like z.css - that way when style sheets are loaded alphabetically it will load in the end. Not the right way but a hack.

Comment: I had't tried it but I suspected that might work. I would only want to do it that way as a last resort though.

Answer (score 0):

"require_tree ." requires all css files in the current directory, try removing that line

```
*= require normalize
*= require skeleton
*= require custom
*= require_self
```

Also, I think if you @import in custom.scss, then you don't need to add it on the assets pipeline's manifest since the sass precompiler takes care of that

```
*= require normalize
*= require custom
*= require_self
```

Personally, I don't like to mix @import's from scss with manifest declarations from the assets pipeline because it's harder to know what's putting what code where.